# What's the difference between CSS inherit and initial?

Tags: css

What exactly is the difference between `inherit` and `initial` in terms of CSS?
For me they always worked the same, for example:

```
a.no-style{color: inherit}
```

will do the same as

```
a.no-style{color: initial}
```

Comment: This may help: http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-cascade/#initial-values

Comment: Check this out: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_initial What happens if you change `h1  {color: initial;}` to `h1  {color: inherit;}`?

Comment: It'll be red of course!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The initial value given in the summary of the definition of each CSS property has different meaning for inherited and non-inherited properties.

For inherited properties, the initial value is used, for the root element only, when no value is specified for the element.

For non-inherited properties the initial value is used, for any element, when no value is specified for the element.

An initial keyword is being added in CSS3 to allow authors to explicitly specify this initial value.

The inherit keyword means use whatever value is assigned to my parent.

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value

Comment: I think If you decided copy and paste the answer, at least you must to mention the source or the author. 

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value

Anyway, good answer.

Comment: I think 90% of people come here because they find technical docs too verbose

Comment: This answer explains it much better than the docs. When I read the docs I was more confused.

Answer (score 20):

The difference is shown when the parent element have redefined the color.

**Inherit:** use the green color from the parent element.

**Initial:** use the initial(black) color.

**Example:**

[image: Snippet screenshot]

```css
.green{color:green;border:1px solid #ccc;padding:6px;}
a {color:blue;}
a.inherit {color: inherit;}
a.initial {color: initial}
```

```html
<div class="green">
  Green text in this &lt;div><br>
  <a href="">&lt;a href=""></a><br>
  <a href="" class="inherit">&lt;a href="" class="inherit"></a><br>
  <a href="" class="initial">&lt;a href="" class="initial"></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 17):

Inheritance is always from the parent element in the document tree, even when the parent element is not the containing block. The initial tag just gives the element its original value.

Answer (score 11):

inherit :

> The inherit keyword specifies that a property should inherit its value
>   from its parent element.

[example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_inherit.asp)

initial :

> The initial keyword is used to set a CSS property to its default value.

[example](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_initial.asp)

Answer (score 7):

inherit

> This keyword applies the value of the element’s parent,
>
> > whether that makes sense or not. Some CSS properties, such as color or
> >     font-family, are automatically inherited, but others, such as display
> >     or margin, aren’t. The inherit keyword should work on all CSS
> >     properties, though.

initial

> This keyword applies the initial value as defined in the CSS
>   specifications. Sometimes this initial value makes sense (float:
>   none), sometimes it’s there for historical reasons (background-repeat:
>   repeat), and sometimes the spec writers made an essentially
>   random-though-somewhat-defensible choice (color: black).

More from [Quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cascading/values.html) site

Answer (score 0):

1. The specification sets a so-called initial value for each property, for the properties `color` and `border-color` for example the value `black`. The initial value is not called default value, the last notation does not exist in CSS.
2. The initial value is often already overwritten by the User Agent. The initial value of `display` for example is `inline`, for block elements like `p` or `div` the UA sets the value `block`.
3. Each property is either inherited or not, the `color` property is inherited, the `border-color` property is not.
4. If the value of an inherited property is not set explicitly with a declaration, the computed value of the parent element is taken.
5. The computed value is derived from the specified value, for example by converting the unit mm to pixels or by extending a relative URL to an absolute URL.
6. If the value of a non-inherited property is explicitly set as `inherit`, the computed value of the parent element is taken, i.e. the property behaves as if it were inherited.

In a nutshell: The declaration `property: initial;` sets the initial value as specified in the specification, the declaration `property: inherit;` sets the computed value of the parent element. The following example illustrates the `initial` and `inherit` values using contextual selectors, i.e. selectors with combinators. The properties `color` and `border-color` of the `p` element are not specified, so the value of the `color` property is inherited from the outer `div` element and the value of the property `border-color` is set by default as the value of the property `color` for each element.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Initial vs Inherited</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <style>
    .frame{ border-style: solid; border-width: 3px; margin: 10px; }
    div{ color:blue; border-color: yellow; }
    body > div:first-child { color: red; border-color: lightgreen; }
    div:first-child { color: initial;  border-color: initial; }
    div div ~ div { color: inherit; border-color: inherit; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="frame">
     Color is red and border is green.
     <div class="frame">Color and border are black.</div>
     <p class="frame">Color and border are red.</p>
     <div class="frame">Color is red and border is green. </div>
   </div>
   <div class="frame">Color is blue and border is yellow.</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Answer (score -2):

`color : initial` is not supported by Internet Explorer.

Comment: John Slegers is right:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial#Browser_compatibility