# Why is display:initial not working as expected?

Tags: css

I am hiding a child image and showing it when someone hovers a parent image. 
Problem is that when the child images shows up, it shows up on right-hand side of the parent image.

I was expecting it to appear below the parent image as that's what the default is. Doesn't setting display to "initial" makes the element get to its default state?

```css
.child {
  display:none;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  display:initial;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <img src="https://lh4.ggpht.com/wKrDLLmmxjfRG2-E-k5L5BUuHWpCOe4lWRF7oVs1Gzdn5e5yvr8fj-ORTlBF43U47yI=w300">
  <div class="child">
    <img src="http://xiostorage.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/test.png" width="200">
  </div>
</div>
```

This question is just for my understanding of CSS property `display:initial`. I am not in need of showing the child image above, below, right or left of parent image.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What's the difference between CSS inherit and initial?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661278/whats-the-difference-between-css-inherit-and-initial)

Answer (score 1):

The value `initial` means different things depending on the property you assign it to.

If you assign it to a **non-inherited** property, like `display` in your case, then its value changes to the `initial` value defined for that property in the [CSS specification](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display) (**not** to a value previously defined in your stylesheet – that's why you get the behaviour described in your question: `display` is being defaulted to its `initial` value, which is `inline`)

If you assign it to an **inherited** property, like `color` for example, then the property takes any value defined previously in your stylesheet, **if** there is any. If there isn't, it defaults back to the `initial` value defined in the CSS specification. (E.g. for [`color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/color) it varies from browser to browser but it's usually `black`)

Relevant links:

[initial - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial)

[initial value - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/initial_value)

[display - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/display)

[inheritance - CSS | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/inheritance)

Answer (score 0):

Well the `initial` value just indicates the value of the whole property. It relies on the property but not on anything else.

**As an example:** The `display: initial;` means inline, this is because that is the designated initial value of property.

In most cases the browser's default is block, because the element is a div.

Not sure if that will benefit your understanding, but there you go.

Comment: Browser's default is "block" so I was expecting "initial" to do the same thing as "block" would do. "block" shows it below the first image. But "initial" does not follow this default characteristic.

Answer (score 0):

So initial is actually the default state for a certain element.

Certain elements like `div` or `p` are by default `display: block`. So setting it to `display: initial` would be the same.

An `img`-Tag is by default `display: inline`. So setting it to `display: initial` is the same as setting it to `inline`.