# What is the default value of the display-box in CSS display module level3?

Tags: javascript, css

I'm thinking about the upcoming display properties in CSS display module level 3. They should make web development easier. But I can't understand how to use display-box properly.
What if I have hidden an element using the code `element.style.displayBox = 'none'` and then I want to show it back? Setting the value `content` seems to be not what I want. Maybe just set empty string `element.style.displayBox = ''`?

Comment: Have you tried it?

Comment: `initial` might be an answer

Comment: Did you try setting it to `contents`, with the "s"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741356/why-is-displayinitial-not-working-as-expected

Answer (score 0):

The CSS display module level 3 doesn't change the style property to `displayBox`, it simply adds more options to `display`, one of those is `contents`

You can read more about it [here in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#typedef-display-box)

Here you can see about browser support:

https://caniuse.com/#search=display-contents

#### Demo

This demo has the `display` property set to `none`, and then sets it to `contents` after 1.5 seconds.

```js
setTimeout(() => {
  const box = document.getElementById('box');
  box.style.display = 'contents';
}, 1500);
```

```css
#box {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <p>I appear after 1.5 seconds</p>
</div>
```